# How to update DataGrid ScrollBar after DataGrid is resized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `DataGrid` above an Expander and whenever I expand the `Expander`, a `ScrollBar` shows up in the `DataGrid`. However, when I collapse the `Expander`, the `DataGrid`'s `ScrollBar` does not go away, even if there aren't enough `Item`s in the `DataGrid` to warrant a `ScrollBar`.

I'm left with a empty `ScrollBar`.

Is there a way to update the `DataGrid` so that the `ScrollBar` logic can be re-executed?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"/>
<Expander Collapsed="Expander_OnCollapsed"/>        

private void Expander_OnCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGrid.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: You could try using `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`. That should work in theory. Hard to tell with no code to work with

Comment: @Cubemaster unfortunately I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Darn, there goes the extent of my knowledge

Comment: You could add an event listener to the expander, I'm pretty sure it has an option for `OnCollapsed` or something like that. Then just set the visibility of the scrollbar in that method

Comment: Could you provide some code? Like It would be helpful to see the XAML and the code behind, so we can see what, if anything, you are doing wrong

Comment: Can't really add too much code as it's proprietary but I modified your code a bit

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly without any code to work with, but you could try:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid">
    <Expander Collapsed="Expander_OnCollapsed">
        <!--Your fancy super awesome code here-->
    </Expander>
</DataGrid>
```

Then in your code:

```
private void Expander_OnCollapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataGrid.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: I have a method in the code behind that is called when the expander is collapsed and that's where I set the visibilty. So far I've tried setting it to auto, disabled, hidden, using UpdateLayout on the datagrid and refreshing the itemssource for the datagrid all with no luck. My code looks fairly similar to your example.